# Cannot boot from working CDROM which is on first place in the BIOS Boot Menu

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios, reinstall

The PC is now with Windows XP Pro. I want to install XP again but cannot run the installation disk.

Motherboard: I have CD which says `Asus A7S8X-MX` but Everest says `Biostar GeForce 6100-M7`.

BIOS: `Phoenix CRU51-M7`.

In the boot menu the CDROM is first:

```
IDE Channel 0 Master      [_NEC_DVD_RW ND-4550A]
IDE Channel 0 Slave       [None]
IDE Channel 1 Master      [None]
IDE Channel 1 Slave       [None]
IDE Channel 2 Master      [Maxtor 6V080E0]
IDE Channel 3 Master      [None]
```

When I insert the installation disk and reboot the old Windows is loaded.

I tried with 3 different disks, so I don't think the disks are broken.

I tried to reset BIOS options to default.

The CDROM opens the installation disks without a problem, also I already burn some disks for backup the data, so it's working.

The only problem that I noticed was that I can't change the boot order with `Page Up` and `Page Down` buttons. Maybe it's related to the kayboard, dunno. But anyway, the CDROM is on first place already.

Is there a way to run the installation disk without reboot, I mean directly from the old Windows? Or some other advices?

My last idea is to try with another CDROM, but it's the final option.

Please help, it's urgent.

**Edit:** I can open the disk. Can I run the installation directly from `Setup.exe`? It opens a window and there is an option for install but I'm not sure whether to click. Is it the same as running installation with rebooting?

Comment: are u sure its a bootable disk ?

Comment: Closing as too localized as requested by the user (the solution found is not an answer to this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your picture shows on which IDE channel the type of device is connected.The Boot Order must be elsewhere in your BIOS setup. You can try to press F10 or F12 to access your boot menu directly when starting your PC.(In case your motherboard has this option).

Comment: Thank you very much! You are definitely right! After your comment I downloaded the manual for the motherboard and there I saw where is the boot order placed. That was the thing that I should do from the beginning, of course. :(